# Why are these two queries different in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I tried this query with good result:

```
select xa.ID_ENTIDAD, xe.nombre_entidad AGENTE_COMERCIAL_QUE_EXPORTA,
GREATEST (fecha_ini_validez,'2021-07-01 00:00' ) FECHA_INI_VALIDEZ,
LEAST (FECHA_FIN_VALIDEZ,'2021-07-31 23:59' ) FECHA_FIN_VALIDEZ,
ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by xa.id_entidad order by fecha_ini_validez) orden
from xm_atributo xa
join xm_entidad xe on VALOR::double precision::integer = xe.id_entidad
where id_tipo_atributo in (
    select id_tipo_atributo from xm_tipo_atributo where nombre='AGENTE COMERCIAL QUE EXPORTA'
)
and fecha_ini_validez<='2021-07-31 23:59'::timestamp and FECHA_FIN_VALIDEZ >= '2021-07-01 00:00'::timestamp
and xe.id_tipo_entidad=1
```

But when I try this:

```
select xa.ID_ENTIDAD, xe.nombre_entidad AGENTE_COMERCIAL_QUE_EXPORTA,
GREATEST (fecha_ini_validez,'2021-07-01 00:00' ) FECHA_INI_VALIDEZ,
LEAST (FECHA_FIN_VALIDEZ,'2021-07-31 23:59' ) FECHA_FIN_VALIDEZ,
ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by xa.id_entidad order by fecha_ini_validez) orden
from xm_atributo xa
join xm_entidad xe on VALOR::double precision::integer = xe.id_entidad
where id_tipo_atributo in (
    select id_tipo_atributo from xm_tipo_atributo where nombre='AGENTE COMERCIAL QUE EXPORTA'
)
and fecha_ini_validez<='2021-07-31 23:59'::timestamp and FECHA_FIN_VALIDEZ >= '2021-07-01 00:00'::timestamp
and xe.id_tipo_entidad=1.0
```

The result is the next error:

*ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type double precision: "BARBACOAL BARBOSA BALLESTEROS "
SQL state: 22P02*

The diference between the two querys is only in the last line (**1** or **1.0**). I dont understand why the result is different.

Comment: What datatype is `id_tipo_entidad`?

Comment: **id_tipo_entidad**  is integer

Comment: Your query is not matching the error. The error is complaining about the string `"BARBACOAL BARBOSA BALLESTEROS" ` and I don't see that anywhere in your query. What is the type for `VALOR`?

Comment: And why would you think an integer value would *ever* be equal to 1.0?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, I agree with you. I looked for the string "BARBACOAL BARBOSA BALLESTEROS" in my tables, but I didn't find it. *VALOR* is type text , but with the filters every value can be convert to number.

Comment: If `VALOR` is text and 'BARBACOAL BARBOSA BALLESTEROS' is one of its values  then this:`'BARBACOAL BARBOSA BALLESTEROS'::double precision::integer` will get your error message: `ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type double precision: "BARBACOAL BARBOSA BALLESTEROS"` In any case `'text_value'::double precision::integer` is not going to work unless 'text_value' is all numeric characters.